# is this possible to copy one schema and create new one

Tags: mysql

In MySQL server is this possible to create a new schema after every 6 months and take whole pack up of existing schema to new one. And make the existing schema as empty.

Is this possible using some procedure which does this job some  time scheduled base.

Your Guidance is much appreciated.

Comment: This would be extremely different in MySQL and Oracle. Which DBMS are you actually using.

Comment: Thanks for reply , am using MYSQL.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: My Boss wants to take pack up every 6 months like this

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of:

```
mysqldump <old_db_name> > dbdump.sql
mysql -D <new_db_name> < dbdump.sql
mysqldump --no-data <old_db_name> > schema.sql
mysql -D <old_db_name> < schema.sql
```

Please see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqldump.html for details

Instead of the last two lines you could just empty all tables in the old db separately

```
TRUNCATE <table_name>
```